# Targeting SQL tables - how to target specific rows & columns?

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, phpmyadmin

I have a WordPress site.

I used phpMyAdmin to create a table in the root directory. I called this new table 'test'.

Currently, this table is made up of three columns: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iupOs.png

[Refer to table structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HRcy5.png)

Now - I am creating this page as a template page for many other pages that are similar to this, but with different data. Here is an example:

```php
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Team Template
 */
?>

<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `test`;";
?>

<section class="intro-single">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-8">
        <div class="title-single-box">
          <h1 class="title-single"><?php echo $first_name ?></h1>
          <h1 class="title-single"><?php echo $last_name ?></h1>
          <span class="color-text-b"><?php echo $job_title ?></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Below is the ideal HTML output:

```html
<section class="intro-single">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-8">
        <div class="title-single-box">
          <h1 class="title-single">first test</h1>
          <h1 class="title-single">last test</h1>
          <span class="color-text-b">title test</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

I would like this to be dynamic, so I could create another page with this template that returns the following HTML input.

```html
<section class="intro-single">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-8">
        <div class="title-single-box">
          <h1 class="title-single">first test2</h1>
          <h1 class="title-single">last test2</h1>
          <span class="color-text-b">title test2</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

UPDATE:

I've made some progress, I was able to get the table to print using the following code.

```php
<?php
//template name: test
?>

<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php
($con = mysqli_connect(
    "localhost",
    "root",
    "pw----",
    "bitnami_wordpress"
)) or die("connection failed : " . mysqli_connect_error());
if ($con) {
    // echo "Connection Successfully";
} else {
    echo "Sorry Some Mistakes is";
}
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$sql = "select * from reg";
$data = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
$total = mysqli_num_rows($data);
if ($total = mysqli_num_rows($data)) { ?>
    <table border="2">
<tr>
<th>id</th>
<th>name</th>
<th>role</th>
<th>phone</th>
<th>email</th>
</tr>
    <?php while ($result = mysqli_fetch_array($data)) {
     echo "
            <tr>
                <td>" .
                        $result["id"] .
                        "</td>
                                <td>" .
                        $result["name"] .
                        "</td>
                                <td>" .
                        $result["role"] .
                        "</td>
                                <td>" .
                        $result["phone"] .
                        "</td>
                                <td>" .
                        $result["email"] .
                        "</td>
            </tr>
        ";
 }} else {echo "no record found";}
?>
</table>
```

With this code, it prints the following on my page:

```
<table border="2">
<tbody><tr>
<th>id</th>
<th>name</th>
<th>role</th>
<th>phone</th>
<th>email</th>
</tr>
        
            <tr>
                <td>id</td>
                <td>name</td>
                <td>role</td>
                <td>phone</td>
                <td>email</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody></table>
```

How can I add this to existing HTML instead? Below is the preferred output.

```html
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-8">
            <div class="title-single-box">
              <h1 class="title-single">name</h1>
              <span class="color-text-b">role</span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-4">
            <nav aria-label="breadcrumb" class="breadcrumb-box d-flex justify-content-lg-end">
              <ol class="breadcrumb">
                <li class="breadcrumb-item">
                  <a href="tel:+">phone</a>
                </li>
                <li class="breadcrumb-item">
                  <a href="mailto">email</a>
                </li>
              </ol>
            </nav>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: `in the root directory` ? What does that mean?

Comment: Wordpress has a whole tranch of functions to query its database. I assume you put this table in the same database as WordPress is using? Or is that what `in the root directory` means i.e. you put it in another database?

Comment: you can look at documentation  https://www.wpdownloadmanager.com/doc/templates/creating-a-new-template/

Comment: @RiggsFolly I'm using Amazon Lightsail so I have a bitnami_wordpress instance. https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZqLou.png

Comment: Please see the updates made to the post.

Comment: With WordPress, use instead the dedicated class [WPDB](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/) … and [all related answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%24wpdb+%5Bwordpress%5D)

Comment: @LoicTheAztec Can you show an example?

Comment: Full of examples from stack overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%24wpdb+%5Bwordpress%5D